# How can I store an int array into a local variable in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, integer, int, mips, memory-address

In MIPS, if I have an array newInt (4,5,6), how can I store that as an integer 456 into a register (like $s0)?

If I try doing la $s0,newInt it simply prints out the address but I want $s0 to literally contain all the numbers found in newInt as 1 single number.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the items in the array have single digits, you have to:

- Initialize `$s0` with 0, and some other register e.g. `$s1` with 0
- repeat until all the array has been read:

  `$s0 = $s0 * 10 + newInt[$s1]`

  `$s1 = $s1 + 1`  (actually it if its an array of ints it would be `+4`)